# PHP if statements - I feel like an idiot

Tags: php, if-statement

I have:

```
<input type="radio" id="flag" name="flag" value="0" <?php if($row['flag_active'] === 0){ echo  'checked="checked"';} ?>checked="checked" /><label for="flag">Inactive</label>
<input type="radio" id="flag1" name="flag" value="1" <?php if($row['flag_active'] === 1){ echo  'checked="checked"';} ?>checked="checked" /><label for="flag1">Active</label>
```

But the second radio button is the one that is always selected. I've echoed out the `$row['flag_active']` and it equals 0.

Also, I've tried:

```
if($row['flag_active'] === 0)
if($row['flag_active'] == 0)
if($row['flag_active'] = 0)
if($row['flag_active'] !== 1)
if($row['flag_active'] != 1)
```

Appreciate the help ahead of time.

Comment: Both have `checked="checked"` outside the PHP anyway

Comment: You're outputting `checked="checked"` in your if statements, as well as directly after each of them. It doesn't matter whether the if statement is true, you're still outputting it.

Comment: Well your radio inputs are always both checked, look at the checked="checked" right after php script.

Comment: Your `if` statements are not related to your problem instead of third one which is wrong here in your case. You just have to delete second `checked="checked"` after your if statements in HTML code.

Comment: Just want to point out that there is no reason to downvote this question, I missed something simple, which is why I said I feel like an idiot in the title, admitting that it's something I must have missed that is simple. I don't know any coder that has read the same line of code 100 times and all it took was a second pair of eyes to find the error. Unfortunately, this is greek to everyone in my office, as they don't have even a rudimentary knowledge of html.

Comment: @Jack agreed. Sometimes this community acts like a pack of wild dogs (However, it has been getting better lately). Don't take it personally.

Comment: @relentless Not taking it personally, just wanted to point it out. I understand down voting questions like "My submit button doesn't work. HELP!" and leaving it at that. But when someone posts their code and what they've tried to do to fix it, it either deserves and up vote or nothing. But that's just my opinion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Um, you have `checked="checked"` outside your `if` anyway. Remove those:

```
<input type="radio" id="flag" name="flag" value="0" <?php if($row['flag_active'] === 0){ echo  'checked="checked"';} ?> /><label for="flag">Inactive</label>
<input type="radio" id="flag1" name="flag" value="1" <?php if($row['flag_active'] === 1){ echo  'checked="checked"';} ?> /><label for="flag1">Active</label>
```

Answer (score 1):

There's a checked="checked" behind the php-code. In your code, every input will have the checked-attribute set as checked.

Answer (score 0):

There are two basic issues with your code:

1). You've set `checked='checked'` outside the PHP clause, so the last item will always be checked.

2). It's really poor for readability & maintainability. You can write this in a much more readable form using ternaries:

```
<input type="radio" id="inactive_flag" name="inactive_flag" value="0" <?= ($row['flag_active'] == 0) ? "checked='checked'" : null; ?> />
<label for="inactive_flag">Inactive</label>
<input type="radio" id="active_flag" name="active_flag" value="1" <?= ($row['flag_active'] == 1) ? "checked='checked'" : null; ?> />
<label for="active_flag">Active</label>
```

Comment: Appreciate the input on the readability, but I think what you posted is worse because it looks like the label is referring to what is below. I have mine in-line on purpose in this case, to avoid the confusion.

Comment: @Jack Could include the labels above. Typically in programming we work with a 90 character soft line maximum, above that, break the line up to make it more readable.

Comment: Generally, I go by the actual readability in my mind. If I have trouble reading it all on one line, I'll split it, unless I think it makes it more confusing.